# Use of Typoscript Variables in HTML5

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

I'm working with Typo3 (6.2) and have a HTML5 template.
I want use variables from my Typoscript in my HTML5 file.

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
     ....
        <img src="img/architecture.jpg" alt="">
     ....
    </body>

</html>
```

and turn this part

```
 <img src="img/architecture.jpg" alt="">
```

into somthing like this,where public_media include the path for the images:

`<img src={public_media}"/architecture.jpg" alt="">`

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this subject should be using the FLUIDTEMPLATE cObject for your PAGE object.
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

This way you will be able to include TypoScript lib Objects into your HTML template.